# Why is flash being persistent on new request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, flash

I have the following code in my controller:

```
  def show
    @activity = current_user.activities.find(params[:id])
    if graph.good_data?(params)
      graph.time_frame(params)
    else
      flash[:error] = "Please enter valid data."
      graph.default
    end
  end
```

When I enter invalid data `flash[:error]` receives a message and everything is displayed accordingly. If I enter valid data after I entered invalid data the action performs as it is supposed. `graph.time_frame(params)` does it's job. However the `flash[:error]` message persists with this next request. If I enter valid data again the `flash[:error]` message disappears. Does anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `flash.now[:error]`, it's specialy for this situation.

Comment: Thank you. I looked at the api but I didn't see that. I must have been blind :)